# Pixel to dp conversion android

Tags: android

This is a basic question. Can anyone please explain the conversion formula used in android:

px = dp * (dpi / 160).

I have seen a number of links but nothing explains it clearly.

Comment: just to be clear I know what each of the term stands for and I have already referred the android dev page . What I want to know is how they arrived at it

Comment: 120 (mdpi) corresponds to the original android phones, see my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this link: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/DisplayMetrics.html#density

That is the most succinct definition I can offer on density. You take this density value and multiply it by the DP number to get your number of pixels.

Also, here are some quick reference numbers on density with relation to DPI.

> low density (LDPI): 120 DPI;
>   medium density (MDPI): 160 DPI;
>   high density (HDPI): 240 DPI;
>   extra high density (XHDPI): 320 dpi

[From Dianne Hackborn:](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/07/new-tools-for-managing-screen-sizes.html)

> To remove the size/density calculations from the picture, the Android
>   framework works wherever possible in terms of "dp" units, which are
>   corrected for density. **In medium-density ("mdpi") screens, which
>   correspond to the original Android phones,** physical pixels are
>   identical to dp's; the devices’ dimensions are 320x480 in either
>   scale. A more recent phone might have physical-pixel dimensions of
>   480x800 but be a high-density device. The conversion factor from hdpi
>   to mdpi in this case is 1.5, so for a developer's purposes, the device
>   is 320x533 in dp's.

Answer (score 0):

dpi=dots per inch.  Its how many pixels are in an inch.  Pixels are actual physical elements of the screen hardware.  DP are virtual pixels-  fake pixels used as an intenral measurement by android.  The number of pixel per dp is device dependent.  1dp= 1/160th of an inch.  This formula is used to convert dps into on screen pixels.

Comment: I need to know the what is the standard pixel size for the android, I am using the xml file for the icons. So it will be available inside the drawable foldr. So which number is standard one to use. 1080p or any other values

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense.  Do you mean the size of a pixel?  The number of pixels per inch?  The number of pixels in a screen?  The number of dp in a screen?  None of these have standard values you can use.  They all change from device to device.  This is on purpose, you're not supposed to assume a device is a specific size, you're supposed to make sure that your layouts and drawables scale as needed.